# Passing event as a parameter to time driven trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a method in apps script which is being invoked by multiple triggers. In that method I want to figure out which is the current trigger that invoked the method. So basically I want the trigger's unique ID. That could be possible if the event is passed to the method as a parameter.

Is it possible ? If yes, a sample code will really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dump the event returned by the trigger you will see it provides it's unique ID.

```
function triggeredFunction(event) {
  Logger.log(event)

  /*
  {
    authMode=FULL,
    range=Range,
    source=Spreadsheet,
    value=a,
    triggerUid=307951997
  }
  */
}
```

That you can then use:

```
if (event.triggerUid === SPECIAL_ID) {
  // Do something special for this trigger ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a unique function for each trigger to call first instead of having all of them directly tied to the main function.

`function triggerFunc1() { mainFunction( 1 ) }`

`function triggerFunc2() { mainFunction( 2 ) }`